# jQuery - getting all attribute values of specified type of elements

Tags: jquery

Okay - so I have many *li* elements with attribute name *data-product-id*:

```
<li data-product-id="11111" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
```

and it's value, the problem is - when I do this in console:

```
jQuery('li[data-product-id]').attr('data-product-id');
```

I get only the first id and I need all of them in that format:

```
'11111', '22222', '33333'
```

Can anyone lead me to a solution. I don't have much experience with jQuery and I need this specific thing to use in Google Tag Manager.

Comment: you need them in an array or in a string?

Answer (score 3):

the thing you need is `each` loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($('li[data-product-id]'), function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('data-product-id'));
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li data-product-id="11111" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
<li data-product-id="22222" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
<li data-product-id="33333" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
<li data-product-id="4444" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
<li data-product-id="5555" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
<li data-product-id="6666" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
<li data-product-id="7777" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
<li data-product-id="88888" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
```

Cheers..!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop with every matching element like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li[data-product-id]').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('data-producer') );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li data-product-id="11111" data-category="ABC" data-producer="XYZ">
<li data-product-id="22222" data-category="ABC" data-producer="ABC">
```